# How to run 2 tags of feature file multiple times in cucumber framework

Tags: selenium, automation, cucumber, bdd

I want to run 2 tags of my feature file multiple in which I am doing following thing

1. Login to website.
2. loging out.

My feature file is:

```
@Login
Scenario Outline: XYZ
When
Then
And

Examples:
|id|  |password|
|x|   |y|

@logout
Scenario:xyz
And 
Then 
When
```

I want to run these two tags multiple times.

My runner file:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="Features",tags = {"@Login,@logout"},glue={"stepdefinition"})
```

Comment: Use a scenario outline...

Comment: I am using scenario outline in which I am giving username and password

Comment: @Grasshopper I want to log in again and again and do the log out again multiple times

Comment: My bad. i just saw the second scenario not the first

Comment: No problem how can i do it @Grass

Comment: You could combine the login and logout in one scenario outline and repeat it with a  examples table containing a counter, if u want to use same login credentials. If u have different users then just mention them in the examples table

Comment: Oh ok is there anyway if i can also use examples in 2 scenario and it will also run again multiple times

Comment: There is no out of the box solution in cucumber for running scenario multiple times. Try a search maybe someone has created a solution... What is ur programming language

Comment: Java language in eclipse